# How to check if the last browser tab of an application is closed

Tags: jquery, cookies

We are making use of encrypted cookies to keep the user's session active across multiple tabs.

If the user closes the browser, the cookies are deleted without any hassle. However, if the user has 2 tabs open, one being the application tab and another tab of some arbitrary site, and the user closes the application tab, the cookies still persist when the user opens a new application tab, and thus, the user session is still active and does not force him to sign-in again.

So my thinking is as follows:

1. Keep track of the open tabs by storing a count value in the browser cookies.
2. Increment the cookie if a new tab is opened
3. Decrement the cookie if a tab is closed
4. Leave the cookie count unchanged if the browser is refreshed

For items 2 - 4, I am utilizing the `window.performance.navigation.type` properties to determine whether a tab was loaded or refreshed. When a tab is opened at first, the `navigation.type` correctly indicates a type of `0`, which is `TYPE_NAVIGATE`. However, if the same tab is refreshed, the type still indicates a value of 0, and only after the second refresh, it switches over correctly to a 1, which is the `TYPE_RELOAD`. So this incorrect interpretation between 0 and 1 causes the cookie to be incorrectly calculated.

Below is my code, perhaps any idea or feedback as to what is going wrong, or perhaps guidelines to a better way of determining if the last tab was closed?

```
var checkTabs = function () {
    //This method gets called at the start of the application

    var isRefresh = window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD;

    //The getCookie and setCookie methods are custom functions to retrieve a browser cookie and its value, and set the retrieved cookie value.
    var tabCookie = getCookie({ name: "WS:T" });

    //If the cookie is not found, we create a new cookie with an initialized value of 0
    if (!tabCookie)
        tabCookie = { name: "WS:T", value: 0 };

    var increment = tabCookie.value;

    //If the navigation type is a navigate and not a refresh, we increment the cookie value    
    if (!isRefresh)
        increment = parseInt(tabCookie.value, 10) + 1;

    setCookie({ name: "WS:T", value: increment, expiry: moment().subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") });
};
```

The `beforeunload` listener is added to the window object and makes reference to the method below:

```
var beforeUnloadTab = function (e) {
        var isRefresh = window.performance.navigation.type === window.performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD;
        if (!isRefresh) {
    //Only decrement the cookie if the tab is closed and not refreshed.
            var tabCookie = getCookie({ name: "WS:T" });
            var decrement = parseInt(tabCookie.value, 10) - 1;

            if (decrement === 0) {
                //If the last tab is being closed, perform the necessary clearing of all session values etc.
            }

            setCookie({ name: "WS:T", value: decrement, expiry: moment().subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") });
        }
    };
```